# Azure ACS - Delete Load Balancer?

Tags: azure, acs

I deployed a swarm ACS and a **Load Balancer** was auto deployed also.

I'm using an **Application Gateway** for SSL offloading and want to point it at my swarm agents.

However, since the swarm agents are configured as the backend pool for the Load Balancer, I can't also make the swarm agents a backend pool for the **Application Gateway**.

I don't need/want the **Load Balancer**, but I can't delete it since it has a backend pool associated with is.

This is the same story for GUI or CLI deployed ACS'.

I asked this same question over at [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/5035ea5d-558c-49c4-9733-0c2b971ed3a7/application-gateway-to-docker-swarm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork#2dc6658e-4f4d-4c34-9ad8-03965fd0ae86), but they eventually directed me here.

Thoughts?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I would suggest editing the ACS template directly to use appgw instead of lb, but I'm not sure how would that work with scaling

Comment: Can you send me your Azure case number, or Microsoft person who directed you to SO?  I can follow-up.

Comment: Hi A Howe, thanks for your reply and technical solution below.  I will test that soon and follow up. 

Here is my case number: REG:117040715573179. 

The moderator over at the MS Forums (link in OP) was the one who suggested posted here also.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions.  The second solution is better since you can deploy a modern swarm mode cluster:

1. For ACS deployed swarm cluster, in the following order make the following modifications:

   1. remove the loadBalancerBackendAddressPools relation ship in the VMSS object
   2. remove the loadBalancer
   3. remove the public ip associated with the loadBalancer.
2. Use ACS-Engine, https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine, to deploy a cluster without a load balancer using the model such as the following:

   ```
   {
     "apiVersion": "vlabs",
     "properties": {
       "orchestratorProfile": {
         "orchestratorType": "SwarmMode"
       },
       "masterProfile": {
         "count": 3,
         "dnsPrefix": "",
         "vmSize": "Standard_D2_v2"
       },
       "agentPoolProfiles": [
         {
           "name": "agentpublic",
           "count": 3,
           "vmSize": "Standard_D2_v2"
         }
       ],
       "linuxProfile": {
         "adminUsername": "azureuser",
         "ssh": {
           "publicKeys": [
             {
               "keyData": ""
             }
           ]
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```